# Motion in field of 2 Coulombic centers (Landau mechanics via Hamilton-Jacobi equation)

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

So i was studying Landau Mechanics about Hamilton-Jacobi Method. The problem after paragraph is motion in field $U(r_{1},r_{2})=\frac{\alpha_{1}}{r_{1}}+\frac{\alpha_{2}}{r_{2}}$. I decide to simplify this problem and set $\alpha_{1} = -\alpha_{2}$. So it becomes motion in field of dipole. Variables separates in eliptical coordinates($\xi,\eta$). And we got Hamilton-Jacobi equation
$$H=\frac{1}{2m\sigma^{2}(\xi^{2}-\eta^{2})}\cdot \Big{[}(\xi^{2}-1)p_{\xi}^{2}+(1-\eta^{2})p_{\eta}^{2}+\Big{(}\frac{1}{\xi^{2}-1}+\frac{1}{1-\eta^{2}}\Big{)}p_{\varphi}^{2}\Big{]}+\frac{2\alpha\eta}{\sigma(\xi^{2}-\eta^{2})}$$
After that we got
$$(\xi^{2}-1)p_{\xi}^{2}-2m\sigma^{2}E(\xi^{2}-1)+\frac{p_{\varphi}^{2}}{1-\xi^{2}}=\beta$$
$$(1-\eta^{2})p_{\eta}^{2}-2m\sigma^{2}E(1-\eta^{2})+\frac{p_{\varphi}^{2}}{1-\eta^{2}}+4m\alpha\sigma\eta=-\beta$$
Here $\beta=\beta+2m\sigma^{2}E$

To find $\beta$ we subract second equation from first and we return to our variables $(\rho,z)$ by also setting $z\rightarrow\infty$.

So $p_{\xi}=p_{z}\sigma\eta$, $p_{\eta}=p_{z}\sigma\xi$, $p^{2}_{z}=2mE$, $p_{\varphi}=0$, $p_{\rho}=0$.

We get
$$2m\sigma^{2}E(2\xi^2\eta^2-\eta^2-\xi^2)=2m\sigma^2(\xi^2+\eta^2-2)+4m\alpha\sigma\eta +2\beta$$
$$2\beta=\beta$$

When $z\rightarrow \infty\;\eta\rightarrow 1$

$$2m\sigma^{2}E(2\xi^2\eta^2-2\eta^2-2\xi^2+2)=-4mE\rho^{2}$$

Finally

$$\beta = -4mE\rho^2+4m\alpha\sigma$$
How ever if we take limit from Landau's expression we should get
$$\beta = -2mE\rho^2+4m\alpha\sigma$$
And this looks logical baceuse this first term is angular momentum. But after recalculating everything i still get this 4 instead of 2. Does anyone know why this can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is likely your last term in the Hamiltonian in elliptical coordinates is $$\frac{4 \, \alpha \, \eta}{\sigma(\xi^2 - \eta^2)}$$

I haven't read Landau's version,  If you are interested in a detailed change of variables from the original ones to the elliptical ones and then the solution to the separable Hamilton-Jocobi equation, I am pasting a derivation I have written some time ago of a similar problem, it is just that in my case $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$. You can always adjust it accordingly.

Here it is:

The original Hamiltonian is
$$H = \frac{1}{2m}\big(\, p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2\,\big)\, + \, \frac{a}{r_1} +  \frac{a}{r_2}$$
where $r_1 = \text{dist}\big(\,(x,y,z), \, (0,0, 0.5)\,\big)$
and $r_2 = \text{dist}\big(\,(x,y,z), \, (0,0, -0.5)\,\big)$. Hence
$$r_1 = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 + (z - 0.5)^2}$$
$$r_2 = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 + (z + 0.5)^2}$$

In general, since any change of position coordinates of the
configuration space extend to a canonical change of coordinates in
the phase space, which comprises of position coordinates and their
conjugate momenta, we get the new Hamiltonian by simply plugging
the new coordinates directly into the Hamiltonian function.

To change the Hamiltonian's variables, it is easier to write it in
terms of the coordinate velocities instead of the generalized
momenta, i.e.:
$$H = \frac{m}{2}\left(\, \Big(\,\frac{dx}{dt}\,\Big)^2 +
\Big(\,\frac{dy}{dt}\,\Big)^2 +
\Big(\,\frac{dz}{dt}\,\Big)^2\,\right)\, + \, \frac{a}{r_1} +
\frac{a}{r_2}$$

Since the Hamiltonian is invariant with respect to any rotation
around the $z-$axis, we can introduce the cylindrical coordinates
$(\varphi, \rho, z)$ where
\begin{align}
&x = \rho \, \cos(\varphi)\\
&y = \rho \, \sin(\varphi)\\
&z = z
\end{align}
and as a result we get the new Hamiltonian by plugging them
directly in the original Hamiltonian
$$
\tilde{H} = \frac{m}{2} \left(\,\rho^2 \Big(\,
\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\,\Big)^2 + \Big(\,\frac{d\rho}{dt}\,\Big)^2 +
\Big(\,\frac{dz}{dt}\,\Big)^2\,\right) \, + \, \frac{a}{r_1} +
\frac{a}{r_2}
$$
where now
$$r_1 = \sqrt{ \rho^2  + (z - 0.5)^2}$$
$$r_2 = \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + 0.5)^2}$$
At this point, we can introduce the intermediate coordinates
$(\varphi, r_1, r_2)$. The coordinate $\varphi$ is unchanged, so
we can think we are switching from 2D coordinates $(\rho, z)$ to
2D coordinates $(r_1, r_2)$. Later, it is going to be easy to
switch from $(r_1, r_2)$ to elliptical coordinates $(\xi, \eta)$
because
\begin{align}
&\varphi = \varphi\\
&\xi = \frac{1}{2}(r_1 + r_2) = \frac{1}{2}\big( \, \sqrt{ \rho^2  + (z - 0.5)^2} + \sqrt{ \rho^2  + (z + 0.5)^2} \, \big) \\
&\eta = \frac{1}{2}(r_1 - r_2) = \frac{1}{2}\big( \sqrt{ \rho^2  +
(z - 0.5)^2} - \sqrt{ \rho^2 + (z + 0.5)^2} \, \big)
\end{align}
For now, we focus on changing from $(\varphi, \rho, z)$
coordinates to $(\varphi, r_1, r_2)$ coordinates, and then to
elliptic coordinates $(\varphi, \xi, \eta)$. Denote by $Q$ a point
with Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ and corresponding
cylindrical coordinates $(\varphi, \rho, z)$, for, say, $z>0$ and
$\rho>0$. More precisely, look at the plane with fixed angle
$\varphi$. It passes through the $z-$axis and the point $Q$. So we
can simply focus on $Q$ in this plane, in which $Q$ has in fact
$(\rho, z)$ as Cartesian coordinates. Denote by $F_1$ and $F_2$
the two focal points with coordinates $(0, 0, 0.5)$ and $(0, 0,
-0.5)$ respectively. In the said plane, the coordinates of $F_1$
and $F_2$ are $(0, 0.5)$ and $(0, -0.5)$ respectively.
Geometrically, the coordinates $(r_1, r_2)$ in the plane can be
interpreted as follows. Given $(r_1, r_2)$, draw the pair of
circles, one of radius $r_1$ and centered at $F_1$ and the other
of radius $r_2$ and centered at $F_2$. The two circles interest in
two common points, as long as $r_1 + r_2
> 1$, and the one with $\rho > 0$ is $Q$. Conversely, given $Q$, one can
calculate the distance $r_1$ between $Q$ and $F_1$, and  the
distance $r_2$ between $Q$ and $F_2$.

Now, changing from $(r_1, r_2)$ coordinates to elliptical
coordinates $(\xi, \eta)$ can be written as
\begin{align}
&\xi = \frac{1}{2}( r_1 + r_2)\\
&\eta = \frac{1}{2}(r_2 - r_1)
\end{align}
with inverse
\begin{align}
&r_1 = \xi - \eta\\
&r_2 = \xi + \eta
\end{align}
Since the kinetic energy term of the Hamiltonian equals the
Riemannian metric tensor of the configuration space, our goal is
to write the latter in the elliptical coordinates. To that end,
let us consider
\begin{align}
&z = z(r_1, r_2)\\
&\rho = \rho(r_1, r_2)
\end{align}
as well as
\begin{align}
&z = z(\xi, \eta)\\
&\rho = \rho(\xi, \eta)
\end{align}
The Riemmanian tensor in cylindrical coordinates is the tensor
$$\rho^2 \Big(\,
\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\,\Big)^2 + \Big(\,\frac{d\rho}{dt}\,\Big)^2 +
\Big(\,\frac{dz}{dt}\,\Big)^2$$ which in elliptical coordinates
should be
$$\rho(\xi, \eta)^2 \Big(\,
\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\,\Big)^2 + a(\xi,
\eta)^2\,\Big(\,\frac{d\xi}{dt}\,\Big)^2 + 2c(\xi, \eta)\left(
\frac{d\xi}{dt} \, \frac{d\eta}{dt}\right) + b(\xi,
\eta)^2\Big(\,\frac{d\eta}{dt}\,\Big)^2 $$ If we keep $\xi$ fixed
and we change only $\eta$, the point $Q = \big(\, z(\xi, \eta), \,
\rho(\xi, \eta) \, \big)$ traverses an elliptical coordinate curve
with foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ and semi-major axis $\xi$. If we keep
$\eta$ fixed and we change only $\xi$, the point $Q = \big(\,
z(\xi, \eta), \, \rho(\xi, \eta) \, \big)$ traverses a hyperbolic
coordinate curve with foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ and semi-major axis
$\eta$. By the properties of conic sections, like ellipses and
hyperbolas, the tangent line at the point $Q$ to the elliptical
curve is the exterior angle bisector of the angle $\angle \,
F_2QF_1$ in the triangle $\Delta \, F_1F_2Q$. At the same time,
the tangent line at the point $Q$ to the hyperbolic curve is the
interior angle bisector of the angle $\angle \, F_2QF_1$ in the
triangle $\Delta \, F_1F_2Q$. Therefore, by the properties of the
interior and exterior angle bisectors of any angle, in particular
$\angle \, F_2QF_1$, the two angle bisectors are perpendicular to
each other. This means, that the elliptic and hyperbolic
coordinate curves are perpendicular to each other. Therefore, the
coefficient $c(\xi, \eta)$ in the Riemannian tensor written in
elliptical coordinates should be zero, so we are looking for the
coefficients $a(\xi, \eta)^2$ and $b(\xi, \eta)^2$ and $\rho(\xi,
\eta)^2$ in the tensors
$$\rho(\xi, \eta)^2 \Big(\,
\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\,\Big)^2 + a(\xi,
\eta)^2\,\Big(\,\frac{d\xi}{dt}\,\Big)^2 + b(\xi,
\eta)^2\Big(\,\frac{d\eta}{dt}\,\Big)^2 $$ The coordinate vector,
aligned with the tangent line at point $Q$ to the elliptical
coordinate curve, is
$$\left( \, \frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta} ,\,  \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial \eta}\,
\right)$$ and the coordinate vector, aligned with the tangent line
at point $Q$ to the hyperbolic coordinate curve, is
$$\left( \, \frac{\partial z}{\partial \xi} ,\,  \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial \xi}\, \right)$$
Hence $a(\xi, \eta)^2$ is the magnitude of the magnitude of the
coordinate tangent vector $\left( \, \frac{\partial z}{\partial
\xi}, \,  \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial \xi}\, \right)$ and
$b(\xi, \eta)^2$ is the magnitude of the coordinate tangent vector
$\left( \, \frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta} , \,
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial \eta}\, \right)$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial z}{\partial \xi} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial
r_2} \frac{\partial r_2}{\partial \xi} = \frac{\partial
z}{\partial r_1} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial
r_2}\\
&\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \xi} = \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_1} \frac{\partial r_1}{\partial \xi} +
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_2} \frac{\partial r_2}{\partial
\xi} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} + \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_2}
\end{align}
or as vectors
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \xi}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \xi} \right) =
\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}, \,  \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_1} \right) + \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial
r_2}, \,  \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_2} \right)
$$
Analogously,
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \eta} \right) =
\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_2}, \,  \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_2} \right) - \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial
r_1}, \,  \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)
$$
So to calculate the magnitude of the coordinate tangent vectors of
the elliptical coordinates, one can first calculate the magnitude
of the coordinate tangent vectors in the coordinate system $(r_1,
\, r_2)$. As discussed above, the coordinate curves of the $(r_1
r_2)$ curvilinear coordinate system are circles centered at $F_1$
and $F_2$. Hence, when we keep $r_2$ fixed and change only $r_1$,
the coordinate curve is always a circle, denoted $F_2, r_2$, with
center $F_2$ and radius $r_2$. Analogously, when we keep $r_1$
fixed and change only $r_2$, the coordinate curve is always a
circle, denoted $F_1, r_1$, with center $F_1$ and radius $r_1$.
Therefore, the coordinate vectors $\left( \frac{\partial
z}{\partial r_1}, \,  \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)$
and $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_2}, \,  \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_2} \right)$ at point $Q$ are externally tangent
to the pair of coordinate circles $F_2, r_1$ and $F_1, r_1$
respectively and are perpendicular to the radius-vectors
$\vec{F_2Q}$ and $\vec{F_1Q}$ respectively. As the tangent lines
to the elliptic and hyperbolic coordinate curves of coordinate
system $(\xi, \eta)$ at point $Q$ are the exterior and interior
angle bisectors of angle $\angle\, F_2QF_1$ of triangle $\Delta \,
F_1F_2Q$, by simple angle chasing, one can check that they are
also the exterior and interior angle bisectors of the angle
between the tangent vectors $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial
r_1}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)$ and $\left(
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r_2}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial
r_2} \right)$. By the parallelogram property of vector addition,
this last fact is possible if and only if the two coordinate
tangent vectors $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}, \,
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)$ and $\left(
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r_2}, \,  \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial
r_2} \right)$, that are tangent to the circles $F_2, r_2$ and
$F_1, r_1$ respectively, have the same magnitude.

The magnitude of vector $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1},
\, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)$ is equal to the
speed with which a point traverses an infinitesimally small
circular arc on the circle $F_2, r_2$ around the point $Q$ as the
parameter $r_1$ changes. To calculate this speed, denote by
$\alpha_2 = \angle \, F_1F_2Q$. Then, the length of an arc on the
circle has length $r_2 \alpha_2$. So the speed we seek is
$\frac{d}{dr_1} \, \big(\, r_2 \alpha_2 \, \big) = r_2
\frac{d\alpha_2}{dr_1}$. Apply law of cosines to triangle $\Delta
F_1F_2Q$ as follows:
$$r_1^2 = 1 + r_2^2 - 2 \, r_2\, \cos(\alpha_2)$$ which yields
$$r_2 \, \cos(\alpha_2) = \frac{1 + r_2^2 - r_1^2}{2}$$ and so
$$\frac{d}{dr_1} \big(\, r_2 \, \cos(\alpha_2) \, \big)
=- \, r_2 \, \sin(\alpha_2) \,  \frac{d \alpha_2}{dr_1}  =
\frac{d}{dr_1} \left( \, \frac{1 + r_2^2 - r_1^2}{2} \,\right) = -
\, r_1$$ so
$$\left|\, \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1},
\, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right) \,\right| =
\sqrt{\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}  \right)^2  + \left(
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)^2 }= r_2 \,\frac{d
\alpha_2}{dr_1} = \frac{r_1}{\sin(\alpha_2)}$$ to calculate
$\sin(\alpha_2)$, we can equate two formulas for the area of the
triangle $\Delta \, F_1F_2Q$
\begin{align}
& 2 \, \text{area}(\Delta \, F_1F_2Q) = \\
&  r_2 \, \sin(\alpha_2) = \sqrt{\,(1 + r_1 + r_2)(-1 + r_1 +
r_2)(1 - r_1 + r_2)(1 + r_1 - r_2)\,}
\end{align}
the latter formula being Heron's formula for the area of a
triangle and thus $$\sin(\alpha_2) = \frac{\sqrt{\,(1 + r_1 +
r_2)(-1 + r_1 + r_2)(1 - r_1 + r_2)(1 + r_1 - r_2)\,}}{r_2}$$

On the other hand, the coordinate $\rho$ is in fact the height of
triangle $\Delta F_1F_2Q$ from vertex $Q$ to the side $F_1F_2$,
and as such $\rho = r_2 \, \sin(\alpha_2)$. Thus, $$ \rho =
\sqrt{\,(1 + r_1 + r_2)(-1 + r_1 + r_2)(1 - r_1 + r_2)(1 + r_1 -
r_2)\,}$$

Now, let us define the angle $\angle \, F_2QF_1 = \theta$ in the
triangle $\Delta \, F_1F_2Q$. Since the coordinate tangents
vectors $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}, \, \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_1} \right)$ and $\left( \frac{\partial
z}{\partial r_2}, \,  \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_2} \right)$
are externally perpendicular to the edges $F_2Q$ and $F_1Q$ of
$\Delta \, F_1F_2Q$, the angle between them is $\pi - \theta$. Let
us construct the parallelogram spanned by $\left( \frac{\partial
z}{\partial r_1}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right)$
and $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_2}, \, \frac{\partial
\rho}{\partial r_2} \right)$, which in this case is in fact a
rhombus, then the coordinate vector $\left( \frac{\partial
z}{\partial \xi}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \xi} \right)$
tangent to the hyperbolic coordinate curves of the coordinates
$(\xi, \, \eta)$ is one diagonal of the rhombus and as such is the
base of an isosceles triangle with angle $\theta$, so its
magnitude is then calculated by applying the law of cosines to
that isosceles triangle $$\left|\, \left( \frac{\partial
z}{\partial \xi}, \, \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \xi} \right) \,
\right| = \left|\, \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}, \,
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right) \, \right| \sqrt{\, 2 -
2 \,\cos(\theta) \,} = \frac{r_1 \sqrt{\, 2 - 2 \,\cos(\theta)
\,}}{\sin(\alpha_2)} $$ Analogous arguments lead to the
calculation for the magnitude to the coordinate vector tangent to
the elliptical coordinate curves of the coordinates $(\xi, \eta)$
$$\left|\, \left( \frac{\partial
z}{\partial \eta}, \, \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \xi} \right)
\, \right| = \left|\, \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial r_1}, \,
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial r_1} \right) \, \right| \sqrt{\, 2 -
2 \,\cos(\pi - \theta) \,} = \frac{r_1 \sqrt{\, 2 + 2
\,\cos(\theta) \,}}{\sin(\alpha_2)} $$ Consequently, we have the
following expressions for the coefficient of the Riemannian tensor
$$\rho^2 \left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)^2 + a^2 \left(\frac{d\xi}{dt}\right)^2
+ b^2 \left(\frac{d\eta}{dt}\right)^2$$ with
\begin{align}
&\rho^2 = (1 + r_1 + r_2)(-1 + r_1 + r_2)(1 - r_1 + r_2)(1 + r_1
- r_2)\\
&a^2 = \left|\, \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial \xi}, \,
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \xi} \right) \, \right|^2 =
\frac{r_1^2 \big(\, 2 - 2 \,\cos(\theta) \,\big)
}{\sin^2(\alpha_2)} = \frac{(r_1 r_2)^2 \big(\, 2 - 2
\,\cos(\theta) \,\big) }{\rho^2}
\\
&b^2 = \left|\, \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial \eta}, \,
\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \xi} \right) \, \right|^2 =
\frac{r_1^2 \big(\, 2 + 2 \,\cos(\theta) \,\big)
}{\sin^2(\alpha_2)} = \frac{(r_1 r_2)^2 \big(\, 2 + 2
\,\cos(\theta) \,\big) }{\rho^2}
\end{align}
To fully calculate the coefficients above in terms of the
coordinates $(r_1, r_2)$ and consequently in term of the
coordinates $(\xi, \eta)$, the only component left is the
$\cos(\theta)$. The latter can be calculated from the law of
cosines applied to $\Delta F_1F_2Q$
$$1 = r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2\, r_1\, r_2 \, \cos(\theta)$$
and thus
$$2\,\cos(\theta) = \frac{r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 1}{r_1\, r_2}$$
so
\begin{align}
2 - 2\,\cos(\theta) &= 2 - \frac{r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 1}{r_1\, r_2} = -
\frac{r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2\, r_1r_2 - 1}{r_1\, r_2}\\
&= \frac{1 - (r_2 - r_1)^2 }{r_1\, r_2} = \frac{\big( \, 1 - r_2 + r_1 \,\big) \big( \, 1 + r_2 - r_1 \,\big)}{r_1\, r_2}\\
2 + 2\,\cos(\theta) &= 2 + \frac{r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 1}{r_1\, r_2} = -
\frac{r_1^2 + r_2^2 + 2\, r_1r_2 - 1}{r_1\, r_2}\\
&= \frac{(r_1 + r_2)^2 - 1}{r_1\, r_2} = \frac{\big( \, - 1 + r_2
+ r_1 \,\big) \big( \, 1 + r_2 + r_1 \,\big)}{r_1\, r_2}
\end{align}
Plugging these expressions in the formulas above and recalling the
change of variable formulas $2\, \xi = r_1 + r_2$ and $2\, \eta =
r_2 - r_1$ we find the coefficients
\begin{align}
\rho^2 &= (2\, \xi + 1)(2\, \xi - 1)(1 + 2\,\eta)(1 - 2\, \eta) = (4\, \xi^2 - 1)(1 - 4\, \eta^2)\\
a^2 &= \frac{(r_1 r_2) \big( \, 1 - r_2 + r_1 \,\big) \big( \, 1 +
r_2 - r_1 \,\big) }{\rho^2} = \frac{(\xi^2 -
\eta^2)(1-2\,\eta)(1+2\,\eta)}{\rho^2}\\
&= \frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{(2\, \xi + 1)(2\, \xi - 1)} = \frac{\xi^2
- \eta^2}{4\, \xi^2 - 1}
\\
b^2 &= \frac{(r_1 r_2) \big( \, r_2 + r_1 - 1 \,\big) \big( \, r_2
+ r_1 + 1\,\big) }{\rho^2} = \frac{(\xi^2 - \eta^2)(2\,\xi -
1)(2\,\xi + 1)}{\rho^2}\\
&= \frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{(1 - 2\, \eta)(1 + 2\, \eta)} =
\frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{1 - 4\, \eta^2}
\end{align}
so the kinetic energy (Riemannian) tensor is
$$(4\, \xi^2 - 1)(1 - 4\, \eta^2) \left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)^2 +  \frac{\xi^2
- \eta^2}{4\, \xi^2 - 1}\left(\frac{d\xi}{dt}\right)^2 +
\frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{1 - 4\,
\eta^2}\left(\frac{d\eta}{dt}\right)^2$$ The resulting total
energy (Hamiltonian with generalized velocities) is
\begin{align}
H = &\frac{m}{2} \left(\, (4\, \xi^2 - 1)(1 - 4\, \eta^2)
\left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)^2 +  \frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{4\,
\xi^2 - 1}\left(\frac{d\xi}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{\xi^2 - \eta^2}{1
- 4\, \eta^2}\left(\frac{d\eta}{dt}\right)^2 \,\right)\\
&+ \frac{a}{\xi - \eta} +  \frac{a}{\xi + \eta}
\end{align}
Switching from generalized velocities to conjugate momenta, we
finally arrive at the Hamiltonian in elliptical coordinates
\begin{align}
H = &\frac{1}{2m} \left(\, \frac{1}{(4\, \xi^2 - 1)(1 - 4\,
\eta^2)} \, p_{\varphi}^2 +  \frac{4\, \xi^2 - 1}{\xi^2 - \eta^2}
\, p_{\xi}^2 + \frac{1 - 4\, \eta^2}{\xi^2 - \eta^2}\, p_{\eta}^2
\,\right) + \frac{2\, a\,\xi}{\xi^2 - \eta^2}
\end{align}
Observe that the Hamiltonian does not depend explicitly on the
variable $\varphi$, only on its conjugate momentum $p_{\varphi}$
i.e. the variable $\varphi$ is cyclic. Therefore,
$$\frac{d p_{\varphi}}{dt} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial \varphi} =
0$$ i.e. $p_{\varphi} \equiv p_{\varphi}(0)$ is a conserved
quantity during the motion. Furthermore, the identity
$$\frac{1}{4\, \xi^2 - 1} + \frac{1}{1 - 4\, \eta^2 } = \frac{4\,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)}{(4\, \xi^2 - 1)(1 - 4\, \eta^2)}$$
allows us to rewrite the Hamiltonian in elliptical coordinates as
follows
\begin{align}
H = &\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)(4\, \xi^2 -
1)}
 \, + \, \frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)(1 - 4\,
\eta^2)} \\
&\, +\, \frac{4\, \xi^2 - 1}{2m\,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)} \, p_{\xi}^2 \,
+ \, \frac{1 - 4\, \eta^2}{2m\,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)}\, p_{\eta}^2 +
\frac{2\, a\,\xi}{\xi^2 - \eta^2}
\end{align}
To integrate this system "explicitly", one can apply the
Hamilton-Jacobi method which turns the Hamiltonian into a
non-linear partial differential equation for the generating
function $S(E, \,B,\, \xi,\, \eta)$ for a canonical transformation
that allows us to simplify the Hamiltonian so much that the
equations of motion associated to it are trivially solvable. The
canonical change of variables from $\big(\,\xi, \, \eta, \,
p_{\xi}, \, p_{\eta} \,\big)$ to $\big(\,\varepsilon, \, \beta, \,
E, \, B \,\big)$ can be extracted form the implicit equations
\begin{align}
&\varepsilon = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}(E, \,B,\, \xi,\,
\eta)\\
&\beta = \frac{\partial S}{\partial B}(E, \, B,\, \xi,\,
\eta)\\
&p_{\xi} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial \xi}(E, \,B,\, \xi,\,
\eta)\\
&p_{\eta} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial \eta}(E, \, B,\, \xi,\,
\eta)
\end{align}
To trivialize the equations of motion of the given Hamiltonian
system, we would like to change the Hamiltonian into a new trivial
function $K(E) = E$ by solving the Hamilton-Jacobi equation
\begin{align}
H\left(\,\xi, \,\eta,\, \frac{\partial S}{\partial \xi}, \,
 \frac{\partial S}{\partial \eta}\,\right) \, = \, K(E)
\end{align}
Explicitly,
\begin{align*}
& \frac{4\, \xi^2 - 1}{2m\,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)} \,
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \xi}\right)^2 \, + \, \frac{1 -
4\, \eta^2}{2m\,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)}\,\left(\frac{\partial
S}{\partial \eta}\right)^2 +
\frac{2\, a\,\xi}{\xi^2 - \eta^2}\\
 &\, + \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)(4\, \xi^2 -
1)}
 \, + \, \frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(\xi^2 - \eta^2)(1 - 4\,
\eta^2)} \, = \, E
\end{align*}
Multiply both sides by the common factor in all denominators
$\xi^2 - \eta^2$
\begin{align*}
& \frac{4\, \xi^2 - 1}{2m} \, \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial
\xi}\right)^2 \, + \, \frac{1 - 4\,
\eta^2}{2m}\,\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \eta}\right)^2 +
{2\, a\,\xi}\\
 &\, + \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(4\, \xi^2 -
1)}
 \, + \, \frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(1 - 4\,
\eta^2)} \, = \, E\, (\xi^2 - \eta^2)
\end{align*}
Now, move all terms that feature $\xi$ to the left-hand side and
all terms that feature $\eta$ to the right-hand side
\begin{align*}
& \frac{4\, \xi^2 - 1}{2m} \, \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial
\xi}\right)^2 \, + {2\, a\,\xi}
 \, + \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(4\, \xi^2 -
1)} \,  - \, E\, \xi^2\, \\
& = \, - \, \frac{1 - 4\, \eta^2}{2m}\,\left(\frac{\partial
S}{\partial \eta}\right)^2 \, - \, \frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m
\,(1 - 4\, \eta^2)} \, - E\, \eta^2
\end{align*}
If we assume that $S\big(\, E,\, B, \, \xi, \, \eta \,\big) =
S_1\big(\, E,\, B, \, \xi \,\big) + S_2\big(\, E,\, B, \,\eta
\,\big)$, the left-hand side depends only on $\xi$ and the
right-hand side depends only on $\eta$. This can work if and only
if each side is equal to a common constant $B$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
& \frac{4\, \xi^2 - 1}{2m} \, \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial
\xi}\right)^2 \, + {2\, a\,\xi}
 \, + \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(4\, \xi^2 -
1)} \,  - \, E\, \xi^2\, = \, B\\
&- \, \frac{1 - 4\, \eta^2}{2m}\,\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial
\eta}\right)^2 \, - \, \frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(1 - 4\,
\eta^2)} \, - E\, \eta^2 \, = \, B
\end{align*}
Express the derivatives squares
\begin{align*}
& \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \xi}\right)^2 \, =  \,
\frac{2m\, E\, \xi^2 \, - \,4\, a\,m\,\xi \, + \, 2m\, B }{4\,
\xi^2 - 1} \, - \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{4 \,(4\, \xi^2 -
1)^2}\\
& \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \eta}\right)^2 \, = \,\frac{
-\,2m\, E\, \eta^2 \,-\, 2m\,B \,}{1 - 4\, \eta^2}\,  -
\,\frac{2m\,p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{8m \,(1 - 4\, \eta^2)^2}
\end{align*}
and take square root on both sides
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\partial S}{\partial \xi} \, =  \, \sqrt{\, \frac{2m\, E\,
\xi^2 \, - \,4\, a\,m\,\xi \, + \, 2m\, B }{4\, \xi^2 - 1} \, -
\,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{4 \,(4\, \xi^2 -
1)^2}\,}\\
& \frac{\partial S}{\partial \eta}\, = \,\sqrt{\,\frac{ -\,2m\,
E\, \eta^2 \,-\, 2m\,B \,}{1 - 4\, \eta^2}\,  -
\,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{4 \,(1 - 4\, \eta^2)^2} \, }
\end{align*}
Thus, the generating function of the canonical transformation we
are looking for, changing the variables $\big(\,\xi, \, \eta, \,
p_{\xi}, \, p_{\eta} \,\big)$ to the trivializing variables
$(\,\epsilon, \, \beta, \, E, \, B\,)$, is
\begin{align*}
S\big(\,\xi, \, \eta, \, E, \, B \,\big) \, &=  \, \int\, \sqrt{\,
\frac{2m\, E\, \xi^2 \, - \,4\, a\,m\,\xi \, + \, 2m\, B }{4\,
\xi^2 - 1} \, - \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{4 \,(4\, \xi^2 -
1)^2}\,} \, d \xi\\
&+ \,\int \ \sqrt{\,\frac{ -\,2m\, E\, \eta^2 \,-\, 2m\,B \,}{1 -
4\, \eta^2}\,  - \,\frac{p_{\varphi}^2(0) }{4 \,(1 - 4\,
\eta^2)^2} \, } \, d\eta
\end{align*}

Let us not forget the third degree of freedom of the system,
represented by the cyclic variable $\varphi$, whose dynamics can
be recovered after applying the canonical transformation above,
obtaining the dynamics of the variables $\big(\, \eta, \, \xi, \,
p_{\xi}, \, p_{\eta}\, \big)$ and then using these to find
$\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will compare it with mine!